# windows freezing after reinstallation from parrot OS

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, boot, freeze

so for a good year or so, I have been using a Debian-based distribution (parrot OS) rather than the preinstalled windows, no problems there. but then I decided to switch back to Windows as I felt it would've been more practical for me at the time.

after burning a USB flash drive with Windows using Rufus, I went through the installation of Windows, and in the disk partitioning section I formated the disk which had parrot and prepared it for Windows, all went well but after a reboot or a reboot due to windows update, the screen would freeze and the spinning dots would just freeze.

- I made sure my usb wasn't corrupt, but I really didnt know what to
  do.
- I would try and be patient and wait it out but nothing really changed
  after hours.
- I tried force resetting by holding the power button the restarting
  but didn't do anything.
- i went through cmd and ran a bunch of disk health commands and disk
  repair commands but same situation.

*small note, when I would shut down and reboot my system, the old grub screen would be the first thing I see, and then it would automatically take me to Windows.*

i eventually ended up having to take it back to a specialist and they told me that they had to reset the SSD or something related. but I want to know, why was switching back to Microsoft Windows from Linux mess up my system so much, is it something i mightve done during installation or is this something only system specific, how can i prevent it next time?

i have the HP Elite Dragonfly G2

thank you for your time, if there are any other questions let me know!

---

Comment: What happened with the new Windows installation had nothing to do with what was there before, it simply was incorrectly installed. If you intended to replace the previous OS then you should have done a clean install - that's probably what they meant by "resetting" - instead of reusing partitions. Furthermore, FYI, there's dual-booting and virtual machines. Keep this in mind for the next time; and Parrot OS ISN'T a normal Desktop Linux intended for daily usage. Users that know as little as shown here are strongly advised to try beginner-friendly Linux distros.

Comment: i have been using linux and different distros on virtual machines for a while but i think you may be correct, i dont think i have done a clean install, ill be sure to take note of that next time, thank you

Comment: Doing a clean install would have removed all partitions in the target drive. The Windows installer would then recreate them as needed, including the ESP (EFI System Partition). Clearly not the case here, that you could see Grub is proof of it.

Comment: small update that reminded me of the problem I faced and the answer that @ChanganAuto provided, found a youtube video that talks about the topic of windows-Linux and the creator seems to have faced a similar problem and provided his own explanation, seemed kinda relevant but here it is fr some extra info for anyone wondering [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PkSx0HiA_vM)